# Google Analytics - Shows "Tracking not Installed"

Tags: google-analytics

This is my google Analytics code:

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'janaganamana.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

1. Login http://www.google.co.in/analytics/
   using the gmail account lselections2014@gmail.com.
2. i wentto  the admin screen and click on Tracking Info- Tracking Code.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem in this???

Comment: It's a very bad idea to post your password here... When did you insert the GA code? Sometimes it takes some minutes to hours before Google recognizes the code.

Comment: Did you try adding ` type="text/javascript"` to the <script>-Tag?

Comment: Is the real time reporting working? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18100752/1682509

Comment: Have you replaced `UA-XXXXXXXX-1` with your tracking code?

Comment: @Reeno no its not working..

Comment: @GuyT: The XXXs have been inserted by Jonas Grumann for privacy reasons. In the original question the correct ID was used

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions shown to the right under "Related". Did you check them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that janaganamana.com is the real domain.... it does not work because you have set the cookie domain to janaganamana.com. However the content is served via an iframe from an IP address:

```
http://184.173.247.142:9094/Election/.
```

If you install the Google Analytics Debugger you will see the error message "Storage not available" which means the _ga cookie cannot be set (since cookie domain and actual domain do not match).

I'm not sure if GA will work with an IP address instead of a domain name, at the very least you will have  to set the cookie domain to "auto".

Comment: thank you i too thinked the same might be the error but was not confirm on that...

Comment: how to set cookie domain to "auto" ??

Comment: ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');